# SSIS Package : Copying .txt file from Cloud server to local server

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Is there any way to copy .txt file from Cloud server to local server? Thanks

Comment: What is the cloud server?

Comment: Be specific..what cloud server?

Comment: Its in Azure. So, I need to create a package which will look up the .txt files on Azure server and if exists it'll move to local server and if not exists it'll do some sort of transformation. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Azure Blob Download Task. You need to download it from here
[Azure Task SSIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/azure-feature-pack-for-integration-services-ssis). Here is more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/azure-blob-download-task